# How to install new packages on Texmaker on Ubuntu?

Tags: packages, installing, ubuntu, texmaker

How do I install new packages on Texmaker? I use Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: Texmaker is only an editor. It has no packages apart from the two that makes up Texmaker itself (texmaker and texmaker-data). I think you should clarify your question a bit. What packages are you planning to install?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You've got some options.

- The easy and consistent way is to use your Ubuntu package manager, Synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center. The Ubuntu repositories contain TeX Live bundles, but their names often don't match a specific package. So, use the search feature to search the package descriptions for the package name. Click to choose and install.
- You could install (extract, copy) the package into your user home directory, to ~/texmf. This is an option if Ubuntu really doesn't provide it or if you would like to use a newer version. In that case, download it from http://ctan.org/pkg/packagename. There are often installation instructions available. On this site, you could additionally check questions regarding [installation of packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages+installing) in general.
- If you want to use the latest version of TeX Live, newer than Ubuntu provides and with its own package management, you could install the original TeX Live. Visit http://tug.org/texlive/. You might also read [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).
- You may follow the suggestions [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72803/easy-installation-removal-of-a-latex-package).

After all, it's independent of Texmaker.