# miktex does not autoinstall via texmaker

Tags: miktex, texmaker

MikTeX on the command line automatically installs missing packages, but when I run latex via TeXMaker, it does not. How can I achieve that?

Comment: oops - it doesn't on the command line either...

Comment: Have you checked the MikTeX settings, whether it is set to install packages on-the-fly?

Comment: yes,I installed it that way, and I have verified it in the MikTex options: Install missing packages on-the-fly: Yes (I'm not familiar with MikTeX, normally I'm on Linux)

Comment: not answering your question but: I always install all packages after installing miktex just to avoid issues like you mentioned above. using the package manager this takes maybe a few hours and around 1-2gb disk space but was always worth the afford while working with huge documents later...

Comment: See [How to install new packages on TexMaker?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10316/10898) and [MikTeX 2.9, install packages on the fly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49338/10898).

Comment: Thanks, that helped, I just had to set the package repository; it now works fine!

Answer (score 3):

Normally TeXMaker has no problems with package installation on the fly.

First setup MikTeX to allow this feature:

- [MikTeX 2.9, install packages on the fly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49338/miktex-2-9-install-packages-on-the-fly)

after this see

- [How to install new packages on TexMaker?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10316/how-to-install-new-packages-on-texmaker)

Comment: Very general and does not solve the problem at all.