# TexMaker autoinstall via MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I have the similar problem like mentioned in 
[miktex does not autoinstall via texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58499/miktex-does-not-autoinstall-via-texmaker) but somehow I am lost. Texmaker is installed.

When I launch the MiKTeX-Package Manger on Windows 8 via mpm then I can somehow follow the first steps of the above link. The manager installs the packages but in TexMaker no auto-install feature :(

I remeber, that I clicked during installation on auto-install-without further asking - but don't know if this is the main problem. Could anybody give me pointer how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49338/miktex-2-9-install-packages-on-the-fly? I'm not sure which steps you mean when you refer to 'the first steps of the above link'. Which steps?

Comment: Hm', well I did the first two screenshots and checking the third screenshot it looks the same way as I've configured it. But to be honest, I don't understand what should be checked in the second options (as mentioned in the text) + I don't know where to set in MiKTeX 'Ask for update' [if this has an influence]

Comment: Which 'second options'? The second screenshot seems fairly clear to me but I'm not a MiKTeX user. Does it work from the command line when you compile? That is, does compilation fail *only* in TeXMaker? Or does it fail generally?