# Missing packages on TexMaker (Windows)

Tags: packages, texmaker, windows, miktex2.9

Using TexMaker and having installed MikTeX, where I opted to install missing packages on the fly (even 'untested' ones), I still find I don't have the packages. I tried to verify the connection source (as suggested here: [MikTeX 2.9, install packages on the fly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49338/miktex-2-9-install-packages-on-the-fly)), however I already have "random" selected and am using Windows 10 -- meaning I'm using the MikTeX console rather than the MikTeX maintenance program suggested above. Other resources are specific to Ubuntu ([miktex does not autoinstall via texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58499/miktex-does-not-autoinstall-via-texmaker)) or vague, or both.

I'm able to compile a dummy TeX file (like 'Hello World') but nothing requiring packages. Obviously the best solution would be to [automatically] download packages as I include them in documents, but a good workaround would be to download a big repo of common packages (that way Anaconda does for Python, for example).

[image: MikTeX settings]
[image: MikTeX packages]

Some specs:
Windows 10
MikTeX 2.9.6637
TexMaker 5.0.2

Comment: Can you install a package (select it and then click on the +)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Now we come to it: "Couldn't connect to server".  Do you know of any workaround besides https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399995/miktex-package-manager-error-message-couldnt-connect-to-server ? On a company machine and unlikely to be able to connect except via VPN...

Comment: Picking this back up -- it must be a proxy issue. I don't think I want *every* package, but I want to be able to grab one when I find one that I need. Does your suggestion download every single package?

Answer (score -1):

My best guess is that you are probably behind a proxy that relays all traffic that goes to the internet. Ask your local IT-experts for the proxy's IP-address and port and then goto

Miktex Package Manager -> Repository -> Connection Settings

Set the checkbox at "Use a proxy server" and enter the address and port.
If the proxy-server requires authentication (try with and without), set the other checkbox "Authentication required" as well.

Comment: All I see if the MikTex console, which has a packages tab but nothing labeled "Repository"... Are you referring to a different program?