# how to Install new font (erewhon), Ubuntu, Texmaker

Tags: fonts, texmaker, ubuntu, installing-fonts

> ! LaTeX Error: File `erewhon.sty' not
>   found.

From http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/erewhon/ a have file     erewhon.tds.zip. There is also readme descriptions to install font, but for Linux with MikTeX. I have Texmaker and the description doesn't work.
"root of the folder you use for personal additions to the TeX trees" is maybe `/usr/share/texmf-texlive`, i copied there directories doc, fonts, tex from unzip erewhon.tds. But what next? Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Don't you have TeX Live installed?

Comment: There is no need to install this package by hand. It is already part of TeXLive and MiKTeX and can be installed with the package manager. Only for a very old TeXLive a manual install maybe needed.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10316/80509